# Detect HTTP status code when linking to external images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails app contains something like the following in a view template

```
<%= image_tag 'http://foo.com/images/1' %>
```

Sometimes, if the url does not contain an image, the hosting site will return a response with a 404 or 302 status.

In this case, the alt-text for the image is displayed.

How can I detect the HTTP response status in order to insert a different image? (such as the next image, or a default 'not found' image)?

Comment: Rails doesn't load the images, it just creates (as the name says) an image tag. The browser is the one actually loading them. If you want to check status codes, you'll either need to make http requests from rails for every image (not a good idea) or use javascript to fetch the images in the browser without actually displaying them (marginally better idea, but not by much)

Comment: Well can I use javascript to detect the returned status on each image?
Would the 'onError' event be triggered by images failing to load?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. I don't know, I've never thought of that. I don't know if you can handle it for individual images, but perhaps you can hook into `document.onerror` (which, I think, collects all errors that occur on the page), and then just check the url that gave the error. Again, I'm guessing here. But it's a nice idea - give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding
    :onError => "alert('error')" 
To the image tag triggers when the image doesn't load.